# Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

If I do  **ionic generate component xxx**

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'
Require stack:

- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/schematics/component/index.js
- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
- /Users/user/develop/myapp/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

  Ionic:

  ```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.2.3
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.2
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.2
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0
  ```

  Capacitor:

  ```
   Capacitor CLI   : 2.1.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.1.2
  ```

  Cordova:

  ```
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 7 other plugins)
  ```

  Utility:

  ```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed
  ```

  System:

  ```
   ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v12.18.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.14.6
   OS      : macOS Catalina
   Xcode   : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
  ```

Answer (score 62):

Seems like it's an **ionic** incompatibility with **angular 10+**

THIS WORKED FOR ME

```
npm uninstall @schematics/angular
npm install @schematics/angular@9.1.0
```

Comment: Had this issue as well on Ionic 5 with Angular 9.1.10 and this worked for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: This is the latest working solution

Answer (score 7):

You may first proceed with npm uninstall @schematics/angular and TERMINAL informs that "removed XX packages and audited XXXX packages" etc, then you may implement npm install @schematics/angular@9.1.0.

Accordingly, ng add ngx-bootstrap provides:

✅️ Added "bootstrap

✅️ Added "ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 4):

Try the code below

```
npm install @angular-devkit/schematics @angular-devkit/core @schematics/angular
```

Comment: Thanks! Just installing schematics caused another error but this one solved it. :)

Answer (score 3):

can you please try to run ng add @angular/pwa@13?

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was to have this:

```
"@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3"
```

instead of "^2.2.0"

My Angular: 10.1.4.

I found this out by creating fresh Ionic project after upgrading Ionic CLI to newest.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is schematics module incompatibility.

1. Find out the version of the @schematics/angular

```
node_modules/@schematics/angular/package.json/#_from
```

2. Find out the version of @schematics/angular which used in the @ionic/angular-toolkit module.

```
node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit/package.json

// package.json 

"dependencies": {
    "@schematics/angular": "^11.2.4",  
}
```

3. Make sure the versions are matching.
4. If the versions do not match, then install the matching version of @schematics/angular.
5. Have an awesome day!

Comment: This kinda worked for me, but it was a very nice first step to find my information. After studying how the Angular team setup their version name, I just used whatever version of Angular I was using at the moment. As of today, I am still on Angular 13, so I used the @schematics/angular pertaining to the version `^13.2.2`. I did the same with the `@angular/pwa` package, since the latest is not compatible with Angular 13.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
npm i --save-dev @nativescript/schematics
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after failing with all kind of suggestions.
I update npm: https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/

Later on Angular: https://update.angular.io/?v=13.0-14.0
and Ionic: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/upgrading-to-ionic-6

It works!!