# "Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to run the below command to install ngx-bootstrap to my project

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap
```

I end up with this error message. See full CLI output below:

```
i Using package manager: npm
√ Found compatible package version: ngx-bootstrap@6.2.0.
√ Package information loaded.
√ Package successfully installed.
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/config'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\source\repos\DatingApp\client\node_modules\ngx-bootstrap\schematics\ng-add\index.js
- C:\Users\user\source\repos\DatingApp\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- C:\Users\user\source\repos\DatingApp\client\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- C:\Users\user\source\repos\DatingApp\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- C:\Users\user\source\repos\DatingApp\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\user\source\repos\DatingApp\client\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-qPbtRR\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I tried uninstalling @angular-devkit & @angular/cli and trying again but to no avail.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue, I found the answer that worked for me here:
[Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/project'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917001/cannot-find-module-schematics-angular-utility-project)

```
npm uninstall @schematics/angular
npm install @schematics/angular@9.1.0
```

Comment: Had this issue and it was resolved even using Angular 11

Comment: Thanks!  I had the same issue.  I ran the above two commands and then was able to run:
ng add ngx-bootstrap                  
Skipping installation: Package already installed
Added "bootstrap
    ✅️ Added "ngx-bootstrap
    � Installing packages...
UPDATE package.json (1353 bytes)
UPDATE angular.json (4728 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem on angular-cli version 11.0.2 when run this command

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
```

i update @schematics/angular version is 11.0.1

```
npm install @schematics/angular@11.0.1
```

and worked

Answer (score 0):

Because ngx-bootstrap require angular schematics module, for that, you need to install **angular @schematics**

you can install using

```
npm i @schematics/angular
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I still get the same message.